# Javascript : Finding sequential order of an array of x,y coordinates from a polygon

Tags: javascript, arrays, polygon, sequential

I've parsed a set of points from a DXF drawing. These points form a polygon but are not in order. I've tried using the center point and angle from each point to determine a sequential order. I need these points in clockwise or counterclockwise to perform the shoelace formula for obtaining the area.

Sample of drawing:
[image]

Array parsed from DXF file:

```
[ { x: 1, y: 1 },
  { x: 6.5, y: 1 },
  { x: 1, y: 26.5 },
  { x: 17.25, y: 26.5 },
  { x: 17.25, y: 13.75 },
  { x: 6.5, y: 7.875 } ]
```

Array after running through sort function:

```
[ { x: 6.5, y: 1, angle: 4.509343763131224 },
  { x: 6.5, y: 7.875, angle: 4.292192266775414 },
  { x: 1, y: 1, angle: 4.145025647537172 },
  { x: 1, y: 26.5, angle: 2.1381596596424144 },
  { x: 17.25, y: 26.5, angle: 1.003432993947379 },
  { x: 17.25, y: 13.75, angle: 0 } ]
```

Sort Function:

```
//SORT ALL POINTS TO PERFORM SHOELACE FORMULA
function sorted_points(points) {
    points.sort((a,b)=>a.y - b.y);

    // Get center y
    const cy = (points[0].y + points[points.length -1].y) / 2;

    // Sort from right to left
    points.sort((a,b)=>b.x - a.x);

    // Get center x
    const cx = (points[0].x + points[points.length -1].x) / 2;

    // Center point
    const center = {x:cx,y:cy};

    // Pre calculate the angles as it will be slow in the sortnumround
    // As the points are sorted from right to left the first point
    // is the rightmost

    // Starting angle used to reference other angles
    var startAng;
    points.forEach(point => {
        var ang = Math.atan2(point.y - center.y,point.x - center.x);
        if(!startAng){ 
            startAng = ang 
        }else{
            if(ang < startAng){  // ensure that all points are clockwise of the start point
                ang += Math.PI * 2;
            }
        }
        point.angle = ang; // add the angle to the point
    });
    // Sort;
    points.sort((a,b)=> b.angle - a.angle);
    //points.sort((a,b)=> a.angle - b.angle);
    return points;
}
```

Can anyone show me a better way to try and sort these points?

Comment: The thing about coords in a polygon is they are in the order they appear. You have to make some ridiculous assumptions to get the order you want.

Comment: The order that results in the smallest circuferance must be the correct one. You can create a graph and then find the shortest route.

Comment: @4thex Must it? It is for this example, but making (6.5, 7.875) a dent in the left edge instead of the bottom right edge results in a perfectly reasonable polygon. Who's to say that's not the correct one?